# output only values with occurence > 2

Tags: csv, google-sheets

I'd like to put in column B all the values of columns A that have an occurence > 2.

E.g: if "john doe" appears more than 2 times in column A then print "John Doe" in column B.

Any idea? I thought of nesting a countif in an index function but I'm struggling with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell B1 (of a google spreadsheet) try:

```
=query(query(if({1,1}, A2:A), "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1"), "select Col1 where Col2 >= 2")
```

or depending on your locale:

```
=query(query(if({1\1}; A2:A); "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1"); "select Col1 where Col2 >= 2")
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: Nope :/ I replaced the "," by ";" to match GSpreadsheet syntax but sill nothing. Seems to be a problem with 2nd parameters of "QUERY : NO_COLUMNCol2."

Comment: the use of semi-colons depends on your locale. Can you share your spreadsheet so I can take a better look ?

Comment: If your locale uses semi-colons, you will have to change {1,1} to {1\1}. I added this formula to my answer above.

Comment: Just noticed that I used "greater than or equal to" (>= 2) in the formula. You can drop the equal sign if you want to return only the names that appear MORE than 2 times. Glad to hear it's working now.. :-)